# « Comment en sommes-nous arrivé à » ou « Comment en sommes-nous arrivés à » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, accord, participe-passé

Doit-on écrire

> Comment en sommes-nous arrivé à

ou

> Comment en sommes-nous arrivés à

Il me semble que les deux sont plausibles mais que la première formulation est plus logique, puisque ce n'est pas vraiment « nous » qui arrivons quelque part, c'est plutôt une expression...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La phrase correcte est :

> Comment en sommes-nous arrivés à

puisque la présence de l'auxiliaire être impose l'accord avec le sujet ("nous"). Au passage, les expressions idiomatiques respectent elles aussi les règles de grammaire et de conjugaison.